# Why does the clip length of an animation not match my math?

Tags: unity, mathematics

I need to re-create an existing animation. The new animation should have the same amount of frames and length and FPS.

Unity shows the following for the original / existing animation:

[image]

As one can see, it says:

- Length: 0.667 seconds
- Frames: 40
- FPS: 60

In order to establish how my new animation file needs to be built, I calculate the duration between 2 frames:

```
_iNumberOfFramesInClip = (int)(nOriginalClip.length * nOriginalClip.frameRate); // says 40

_fFPS = nOriginalClip.frameRate; //says 60

_fDurationOf1Frame = nOriginalClip.length / _iNumberOfFramesInClip; // says 0.01666667f
```

Now I create the new animation files using a Recorder.

I do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _iNumberOfFramesInClip; i++)
{
    _Recorder.TakeSnapshot(_fDurationOf1Frame);
}
```

_Recorder.currentTime says: 0.65

I log the following values:

```
Frame 1 starts at 0 
Frame 2 starts at 0.01666667
Frame 3 starts at 0.03333334 
Frame 4 starts at 0.05 
Frame 5 starts at 0.06666667 
Frame 6 starts at 0.08333334 
Frame 7 starts at 0.1 
Frame 8 starts at 0.1166667 
Frame 9 starts at 0.1333333 
Frame 10 starts at 0.15
Frame 11 starts at 0.1666667 
Frame 12 starts at 0.1833333 
Frame 13 starts at 0.2 
Frame 14 starts at 0.2166667 
Frame 15 starts at 0.2333333 
Frame 16 starts at 0.25 
Frame 17 starts at 0.2666667 
Frame 18 starts at 0.2833334 
Frame 19 starts at 0.3 
Frame 20 starts at 0.3166667 
Frame 21 starts at 0.3333334 
Frame 22 starts at 0.3500001 
Frame 23 starts at 0.3666668 
Frame 24 starts at 0.3833334 
Frame 25 starts at 0.4000001 
Frame 26 starts at 0.4166668
Frame 27 starts at 0.4333335 
Frame 28 starts at 0.4500002 
Frame 29 starts at 0.4666668 
Frame 30 starts at 0.4833335 
Frame 31 starts at 0.5000002 
Frame 32 starts at 0.5166668 
Frame 33 starts at 0.5333335 
Frame 34 starts at 0.5500001 
Frame 35 starts at 0.5666668 
Frame 36 starts at 0.5833334 
Frame 37 starts at 0.6000001 
Frame 38 starts at 0.6166667 
Frame 39 starts at 0.6333334 
Frame 40 starts at 0.65
```

So Frame 40 should end at (0.65f + 0.01666667f).
However, the new clip's length is displayed as 0.65 seconds:

[image]

This does not seem correct to me. The length should be 0.667 as in the original clip.

Where do I go wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Wild guess, but are you sure your animation import setting doesn't have animation compression turned on? Not sure if that would change anything, but might as well give it a try.

Comment: @prithul No, it does not have "Animation Compression" or "Resample Curves" on.